# Person A, Person B and Person C are all plotting to shoot Person D.

Tags: probability

> Person A, Person B and Person C are all plotting to shoot Person D. If one of the three has both an opportunity and the revolver, then that person shoots Person D. Otherwise, Person D escapes. Exactly one of the three has an opportunity with the following probabilities:
>
> P(A has opportunity) = 3/6,
>
> P(B has opportunity) = 2/6,
>
> P(C has opportunity) = 1/6.
>
> Exactly one has the revolver with the following probabilities, regardless of who has an opportuntity:
>
> P(A has revolver) = 1/8,
>
> P(B has revolver) = 3/8,
>
> P(C revolver) = 4/8.
>
> Answer the question:
>   1) What is the probability that Person D is shot?
>
> 2) What is the probability that Person D is shot, given that Person C does not have the revolver?
>
> 3)What is the probability that Person B had an opportunity, given that Person D was shot?

1) 13/48

2) 9/24

3) I'm not really sure how to solve this. Should I use a reverse probability tree?

P.S. Will the probability change if person B doesn't have an opportunity? Or if he doesn't have a revolver?

I would appreciate any help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you add your calculations?  Your work/process is always much more important than your eventual answers ...

Comment: You have answered 1) correctly, but I am not sure if 2) is correct. So your working would be useful to see. Also the method for 3) is quite similar to 2).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the edit? The probability we seek is **about** B having an opportunity, we are not **given** that B has an opportunity. So when you say "Will the probability change if person B doesn't have an opportunity?", this doesn't make sense - this is not prior information we were given to start with. As for the other condition, you'll find he has to have the revolver if $D$ has been shot and $B$ has an opportunity. However, if we are _given_ B doesn't get the revolver, then the probability of $B$ having an opportunity given $D$ shot and $B$ doesn't get revolver is 0.

Comment: Oh, ok, it's my mistake. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: No problem, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Denote player $X$ having an opportunity as $X_O$, having a revolver as $X_R$, and being shot as $X_S$. Then $$P(B_O|D_S)=\frac{P(B_O\cap D_S)}{P(D_S)}=\frac{P(B_R)}{P(D_S)}$$You can now evaluate this using your answer to question 1).

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you!! I understand the first part, but how did you deduce that P(Bo∩Ds)=P(Br)?

Comment: Because $B_O \cap D_S$ means $B$ has an opportunity, and $D$ is shot. The only way this can happen is if $B$ also got the revolver - if someone else got the revolver, then since $B$ was the one with the opportunity, $D$ wouldn't have been shot. So the event $B_O\cap D_S$ is exactly the same as $B_R$.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thank you!! :)